# javascript inline vs. traditional registration

Tags: javascript, inline, registration

I am a js newbie and I'm trying to grasp inline vs. traditional registration.  Code block 1 (inline) works fine, but code block 2 (traditional) does not. Can anyone shed light on my error?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script>
function gethash() {
var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(name);
alert("Hello, " + name +".\nYour hash is " + hash)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="gethash()" value="Get your hash" />
</body>
</html>
```

This attempt to use traditional registration does not work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function gethash() {
var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(name);
alert("Hello, " + name +".\nYour hash is " + hash)
}
document.getElementById('myname').onclick = gethash;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Get your hash" id="myname" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such element at the point where you're trying to bind something using `onclick`. Move that line to the bottom of the file.

If you look at the console, you should see an error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

This should fix it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Get your hash" id="myname" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function gethash() {
var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(name);
alert("Hello, " + name +".\nYour hash is " + hash)
}
document.getElementById('myname').onclick = gethash;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

That leads us to the better way of doing this. Using [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload), you can execute the JS code after everything has loaded.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('myname').onclick = gethash;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `document.getElementById('myname').onclick = gethash;`, the element you're trying to bind the event to does not yet exist.

You need to put your code in an onload event, like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function gethash() {
                var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
                var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(name);
                alert("Hello, " + name +".\nYour hash is " + hash)
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById('myname').onclick = gethash;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" value="Get your hash" id="myname" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Using onload is not ideal, since it waits for all resources to load before it fires. Using the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) event would be better, or for cross-browser compatibility, check out libraries such as jQuery.

---

On a side-note, separating your presentation and logic is a very good idea, so inline event handlers should be avoided.

Comment: _On a side-note, separating your presentation and logic is a very good idea, so inline event handlers should be avoided._ - thank you, Cameron - that is exactly what I'm trying to learn :-)

Comment: Actually, logic, content and presentation should all be separated.

Answer (score 0):

sachleen is correct (the code below works) - although you could simply move the whole javascript block to the end of the `body` tag:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Get your hash" id="myname" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function gethash() {
            var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
            var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(name);
            alert("Hello, " + name +".\nYour hash is " + hash)
        }
        document.getElementById('myname').onclick = gethash;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```